# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when using shared component

Tags: angular

I am using a shared custom dropdown component, the shared component have isCategorized @input property, when I open a dialog that has this component with isCategorized set true then press a button that will open another dialog which also has this shared component with isCategorized set to false I get  ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error

select component

```
 <div class="row" *ngIf="isCategorized">
        <div class="col-md-10" (mousedown)="SelectItem(item)">
          <span>{{item?.name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div [className]="'col-md-2 pr-0'">
          <nb-icon (mousedown)="edit.emit([item,i])" icon="edit-outline" status="info"></nb-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
```

in first Dialog :

```
   <ngx-select #selectmerchants [isCategorized]="transactionType === 'Categorized'
                                    || transactionType === 'transfer'"
                                    [form]="transactionLabelsForm" controlForm="merchantId"
                                    placeHolder="Choose merchant"
                                    [list]="merchants | async"
                                    [selected]="merchantName | async"
                                    (edit)="Edit($event)"
                                    (object)="SelectMerchant($event)"></ngx-select>
                        </ng-container>
```

in second Dialog:

```
 <ngx-select   [isCategory]=true [width]="400" placeHolder="Choose Country" [list]="countriesList"
                                    [selected]="" [form]="merchantForm" controlForm="CountryId"
                                    (object)="SelectCountry($event)"></ngx-select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this issue by converting isCategorized property to a setter and set a setTimeout block and inside that block a set other property to the value of isCategorized like this:

```
@Input() set isCategorized(value) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.categorized = value;
    }, 500);
}
```